# Drops are not spherical?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, surface-tension

Surface tension tells us drops are spherical but dew drops or drops large ammount of big substance really fallapart or are not mainly a most perfect sphere.
Is there hold the following and what is value of a in:
$$\delta P=2T/a$$

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu%2Fhbase%2Fsurten2.html&psig=AOvVaw0E3k7vXRB5eh5OsNw-8lvp&ust=1607848942017000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKD_x5yGyO0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drops are only spherical if they are in free fall (neglecting air resistance) or if they are small enough and light enough that the force of gravity on then is much smaller than surface tension.

$$\Delta P = \frac {2T} a$$

is a first order approximation to the [Young-Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation) in which we assume that the width of the liquid layer surrounding the drop is small compared to its size, so the radius of curvature of the inside and outside of this liquid layer are both equal to $a$. If a drop is large enough to be affected by gravity then there will be a vertical pressure gradient within the drop so $a$ will not be constant and the drop will not be spherical.

Answer (score 0):

> Surface tension tells us drops are spherical

Yes. **All other factors being equal**, superposition of molecular forces results in net inward-directed force, attracting surface molecules towards bubble center :

[image]

So we can say that surface tension is much like a centripetal force, like gravity for example. That's why planets are spheres too ! Just difference is that gravitational forces attracts each mass unit towards center of mass, and surface tension - only surface molecules. Other molecules are pushed to the center only due to pressure from surface tension. Much like if you would put elastic hair rubber band around some deformable object, then it would be squeezed. So water, can't be considered totally incompresible material.

If you see not spherical drops like this :

[image]

It means that other forces comes into play, like gravity,drag force,etc. which distorts effects of surface tension.